# What is the difference between `fallocate --dig-holes` and `fallocate --punch-hole` in Linux?

Tags: linux, files, filesystems, sparse-files, fallocate-command

I totally understand that `--dig-holes` creates a sparse file in-place. That is, if the file has holes `--dig-holes` options removes those holes:

Let's take it in a very simplified way, let's say we have a huge file named non-sparse:

*non-sparse:*

```
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00
\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00
\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00
bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00
\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00
cccccccccccccccccccccccccccc
```

*non-sparse* has many zeros in it, assume that the interleaving zeros are in Gigabytes. `fallocate --dig-holes` de-allocates  the space available for the zeros (holes) where the actual file size remains the same (preserved).

Now, there's `--punch-hole` what does it really do? I read the man page, still don't understand:

```
-p, --punch-hole
              Deallocates space (i.e., creates a hole) in the byte  range
              starting at offset and continuing for length bytes.  Within
              the specified range, partial filesystem blocks are  zeroed,
              and  whole  filesystem  blocks  are  removed from the file.
              After a successful call, subsequent reads from  this  range
              will  return  zeroes.
```

Creating hole, that's the opposite of `--dig-hole` option it seems like that, and how come that digging a hole isn't the same as creating a hole?! Help! we need a logician :).

The naming of the two options are synonymous linguistically which perhaps makes confusion.

What's the difference between `--dig-holes` and `--punch-holes` operationally (not logically or linguistically please!)?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`--dig-holes` doesn’t change the file’s contents, as determined when the file is read: it just identifies runs of zeroes which can be replaced with holes.

`--punch-hole` uses the `--offset` and `--length` arguments to punch a hole in a file, regardless of what the file contains at that offset: it works even if the file contains non-zeroes there, but the file’s contents *change* as a result. Considering your example file, running `fallocate --punch-hole --offset 2 --length 10` would replace ten `a` characters with zeroes, starting after the second one.

Answer (score 12):

In short:

- `--dig-holes` makes a file sparse without modifying its contents (as seen by a program reading it).
- `--punch-hole` creates a hole in a file, possibly modifying existing data.

The difference is that `--dig-holes` analyzes the file for areas that can be made sparse (using `--offset` and `--length`, if supplied, to indicate the range in the file to analyze), whereas `--punch-holes` uses `--offset` and `--length` to actually *zero out* a part of a file to create a hole.

Note also the plural "dig holes" vs. the singular "punch hole".

From [the manual](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/fallocate.1.html), regarding `--dig-holes`:

> You can think of this option as doing a `cp --sparse` and then
>                 renaming the destination file to the original, without the
>                 need for extra disk space.